# update-grub warning regarding GRUB_DEFAULT title name

Tags: grub2

**When setting GRUB_DEFAULT to:**

```
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (18.04) (auf /dev/nvme0n1p2)
```

`update-grub` emits a warning (3 times) that I should not use this "old title", but should use one of the following, depending on my "version".

**For versions pre 2.00:**

```
Advanced options for Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (18.04) (auf /dev/nvme0n1p2)>Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (18.04) (auf /dev/nvme0n1p2)
```

**For versions 2.00 or higher:**

```
gnulinux-advanced-c40111ac-c9cb-43b2-b72b-e6d86975cd57>gnulinux---c40111ac-c9cb-43b2-b72b-e6d86975cd57
```

I assumed that this warning means the grub version with "version". So I picked the latter format, as my grub is 2.02-2ubuntu8.

But it didn't worked. When changing back to the "old title" it works again.

```
Warnung: Bitte verwenden Sie nicht den alten Titel
»Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (18.04) (auf /dev/nvme0n1p2)« für GRUB_DEFAULT, verwenden Sie
»Advanced options for Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (18.04) (auf /dev/nvme0n1p2)>Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (18.04) (auf /dev/nvme0n1p2)« (für Versionen vor 2.00) oder
»gnulinux-advanced-c40111ac-c9cb-43b2-b72b-e6d86975cd57>gnulinux---c40111ac-c9cb-43b2-b72b-e6d86975cd57« (für 2.00 oder neuer)
```

Why shouldn't I use the normal "old" title and what would be the correct title then? Or should I ignore this message?

**System informations:**

```
Linux htpc7even3 4.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 6 11:12:41 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: The capitalization and spacing are important... it's got to say `Gnulinux-advanced-c40111ac-c9cb-43b2-b72b-e6d86975cd57> gnulinux --- c40111ac-c9cb-43b2-b72b-e6d86975cd57` exactly... (you have it incorrect in your example).

Comment: @heynnema The error message is copy & paste. I used the names mentioned there via copy & paste as well.

Comment: Just copy the stuff that I show in blue, in my previous comment, then edit /etc/default/grub, and paste the clipboard into the appropriate place in the file, and then do `sudo update-grub`. The way that I show in my answer is **still** the much easier way :-)

Comment: I will try this as well (I have to find a time slot where I have time and my htpc system has no schedules), but the solution to remember the last selected item is (easy and I know it already for years, but is) no option as I explained.

Answer (score 3):

The [Grub-manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Simple-configuration) states:

> Previously it was documented the way to use entry title. While this still works it’s not recommended since titles often contain unstable device names and may be translated

Your entry-title contains a device-name (`/dev/nvme0n1p2`). Devices names may change if you remove or add a drive or reconnect the existing drive to a different slot.

In such a case the menu-entry-titles in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` would be updated when you run 'update-grub' and this would make the default (which remains the same) invalid. Thus you get a warning, you can still use it if you want and knowing what you're doing, never add or remove drives.

It's recommended to use the menu-entry-ID instead which does not contain a device name but the UUID of the partition you want to boot from, that's much more stable.

You don't need to use the two-level-identifier. I just copied the identifier of my first menu-entry from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and set

```
GRUB_DEFAULT='gnulinux-simple-06a41c79-a7ff-4fd2-86eb-fb4f510bf31a'
```

and then ran `sudo update-grub` which finished silently (no error, no warning), also no problems during reboot.

Comment: Yes this absolutely makes sense and I would prefer a stable identifier therefore. But it didn't worked in the way the warning message stated. Is your proposal to use the "menu-entry-ID" different? Do I need these two level identifiers? (of course I can try out everything, but this costs time and the htpc system only has limited "free times" slots :D :D )

Comment: @Nicolas I think you had a syntax problem. You don't need two-level-identifier, see my example in my edit.

Comment: Ah, brilliant, thank you, I will try this out!

Comment: I think this is even better than to use the advanced options id, the kernel-version and the related menuentry could disappear due to autoremove.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest to edit `/etc/default/grub` like this...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

---

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

---

`sudo update-grub`

This way, GRUB remembers the last OS you selected, and will continue to reboot to that same OS until you select a different OS.

Much simpler than trying to match textual names, or using raw numbers.

Comment: Yes I know this option. But I want to use a solution that points to the target system by configuration, because it is an htpc system. This system turns on and off automatically. So, I would have to connect a keyboard to make the initial selection and if this get lost somewhen (for whatever reason), the system would boot wrongly. (note that this is an intermediate solution only, until I am able to switch the boot device)

Comment: @Nicolas yes, but my solution doesn't require constant reconfiguration every time the kernel gets updated. And, as you've found, finding the correct title text to use can be tricky. Lastly, once an OS has been selected, it doesn't "get lost somewhere".

Comment: @Nicolas you can find the correct text to use by reviewing the output of `grep -i menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: Thank you heynnema. In fact, this is what mook765 answered below. I still got no chance to try this all out, as my box is busy with tv recording schedules... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What's I've always done on this is to match exactly what shows up in the "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" Grub menu. So if it looks like this:

[image]

I use

`GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.0-25-generic"`

This produces no errors or warnings when `sudo update-grub` is run.

Comment: The kernel just needs to be upgraded a few times and this one autoremoved, then `GRUB_DEFAULT` points to nowhere and you'd have to change it manually.

Comment: I will try this. It is ok for me to re-evaluate this setting at each kernel upgrade.

Comment: Cool grub background worth an upvote.

Answer (score -1):

In Ubuntu (or any derivative) you can simply install grub-customizer (it is in the repositories) and open it. Then "General settings" and in "predefined" choose the kernel you want to start with. Save. That's it.