# How to add older linux kernel to grub?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I used `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` to find out I have the following kernel versions:

```
rc  linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic                4.18.0-15.16~18.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.18.0-25-generic                4.18.0-25.26~18.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic                 5.0.0-23.24~18.04.1                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.0.0-25-generic                 5.0.0-25.26~18.04.1                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04                5.0.0.25.82                                  amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

I want to add 4.18.0-25 to grub so that it boots into it by default, but I can't figure out where these kernels are located so that I can add them to grub? How can I do that. Also after I identify where the image files are, do I only need to copy them to /boot run `sudo update-grub`? Or is there more I need to do?

Comment: Thank you! How can I get the removed kernels back?

Comment: Once you get the kernel installed, you can look at this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1168445/243321 to see how to set grub to boot into it by default.

Comment: The OP wants to keep using an older kernel, just wondering if he has to do anything to stop software updater from removing it afterwards?

Comment: @crip659 You can mark hold it. Then it never gets auto-removed.

Comment: @user535733 Please post a full answer that can be accepted. Otherwise this question will keep reappearing as unanswered for a quad-zillion years.

Comment: @user535733 Thank you. Upvoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'rc' at the beginning of the line means that the package has been removed. 
Currently installed packages are the 'ii' lines.

You are looking at the database of packages that dpkg is aware of, installed or not, including packages from the past that have since been removed.

If you really want to re-install an older kernel, there's a good chance that simply telling apt will do the trick: `sudo apt install linux-image-4.18.0-25-generic`

Since Ubuntu regularly wants to upgrade you to a newer kernel, you can apt-mark the package so it doesn't get removed again: `sudo apt-mark hold linux-image-4.18.0-25-generic`.

Someday, when you change your mind and DO want to remove the old kernel: `sudo apt-mark unhold linux-image-4.18.0-25-generic`